# Finding file icon given a MIME type using GTK

Tags: gtk, pygtk, mime-types

Is there a way to find out which icon to use for a given MIME type, using GTK/pygtk?

I know about `gio.File(filename).query_info("standard::icon").get_icon()`, but I need to find the icon without having to read the file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `gio.content_type_get_icon()`.  E.g.:

```
>>> gio.content_type_get_icon ('text/python')
<gio.ThemedIcon at 0xb7d0f734: text-python, gnome-mime-text-python, text-x-generic>
```